# Cannot set property of NULL object

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch function that does some basic math with values that are entered.

```
 $scope.$watch('currentItem.JobOriginalContract -- currentItem.JobTotalCO', function (value) {
    $scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract = value;
});
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'JobRevisedContract' of null

When I do this...

```
$scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract = null;
$scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract = {};
$scope.$watch('currentItem.JobOriginalContract -- currentItem.JobTotalCO', function (value) {
    $scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract = value;
});
```

...the error message goes away, but it causes everything else not to work. It gives no error. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the object exists before trying to set properties on it:

```
if (!$scope.currentItem) $scope.currentItem = {};
$scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract = value;
```

Comment: well, that worked perfect thank you, cant accept the answer yet. but maybe you could help with a similar problem i have. it hasnt been solved yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790184/how-to-correct-this-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $scope.$watch('currentItem.JobOriginalContract -- currentItem.JobTotalCO', function (value) {
    $scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract={};
  $scope.currentItem.JobRevisedContract = value;

  });
```